# Algebraic equations - factoring cubic and degree four expressions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I'm practicing for an entry exam to a foreign university and one of the requirements is understanding

> "Algebraic equations - factoring cubic and degree four expressions"

Could someone give me an example of this? I feel like the english is off. I have not had an issue understanding any of the previous questions.. thanks.

Comment: For example, how would you factor the expression $x^3+3x^2+3x+1$? In general, one may need to solve the cubic or quartic, but a general understanding would be spotting patterns between coefficients and playing with polynomials, so factorization can be done by observation. On that note, you are applying for an undergraduate course, I presume?

Comment: Yes, going for computer science :)

Comment: Well, do not trust me completely, I only turned 13 a few months back. Have you managed to factorize the given expression?

Comment: I'm reviewing it in khan academy now.. this looks to be Algebra I not Algebra II level?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг  we trust Olof Mellberg completely

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you for trusting Olof Mellberg. the answer below is also brilliant, it certainly elaborates more than I expected! One question : Descartes' rule is helpful, but is it a necessity?

Comment: @WillJagy or actoh can one of you run me through a full factor? It'll help to refresh my memory since i'm doing algebra 2 no problem

Comment: @whataboutme1 My question to you would be what you already know. My apologies, since I don't know exactly what is covered in Algebra I level in your country (and I went through all these algebra I/II etc. in such a short time, I feel like I'm on Algebra five).

Comment: perfect square factoring, or just factoring in general like x^2+10x+25 = (x * 5)(x * 5) .. sort of a big question there

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг
Could you just write out one example solved out? (Like the answer to Will Jagy question). Would save me a lot of googling to understand because I learn from the answers

Comment: To give an example : Suppose we are factorizing $x^3-x^2+x-1$. We first use the fact that $1$ is the product of the roots, so if there are any integer roots, they can only be $1$ and $-1$. Substituting $x=1$ gives $0$ value to the expression. By the remainder theorem, $(x-1)$ divides $x^3-x^2+x-1$. Now, carry out long division, to show that the quotient is $x^2-1$. By the difference of squares formula (or doing what we did again with the previous polynomial), we see this is $=(x-1)(x+1)$, so the final factorization is $(x+1)(x-1)^2$. This is only an illustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

factor
$$ x^4 + 9x^2 + 4x + 21 $$
The central parts are the rational roots theorem, how do divide out if there is a root, and the Gauss theorem on content, which says that a polynomial with integer coefficients that factors with rational coefficients ALSO factors with all integer coefficients.